# How to remove outliers of a dataset in R?

Tags: r

Can anyone tell me how to remove outliers of the first column and keep the second column at the same time? My dataset is as follows:

```
Y     X

79  1.00000000

70  1.00000000

10  0.90000000

78  1.00000000

...  ...
```

Comment: What procedure are you wanting to use for outlier removal? +- 2 sd, box trim, recursive?

Comment: Have look here http://www.unige.ch/ses/sococ/cl/r/tasks/outliers.e.html.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define what you mean but outlier, but for example, say any values that are not within plus or minus two standard deviations of the mean are outliers:

```
m<-mean(df$Y)
sd<-sd(df$Y)
out.u<-m+2*sd
out.l<-m-2*sd
```

This will replace the outlier with NA:

```
rem.out<-ifelse(df$Y>out.u or dfY<out.l,NA,df$Y)
```

And this will remove the entire row:

```
no.out<-subset(df,df$Y<out.u & df&Y>out.l)
```

Comment: The question asks how to remove the outlier in Y but keep the value in X.  This removes the entire row.

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined an outlier to be less than (or greater than) a specific value, then `ifelse` can be used.  For example, if an outlier is defined to be less than or equal to 15 and you want to remove the value in `Y` and keep the value in `X` you can do

```
> dat <- data.frame(Y = c(79, 70, 10, 78), X = c(1, 1, 0.9, 1))
> dat$Y <- ifelse(dat$Y <= 15, NA, dat$Y)
> dat
##    Y   X
## 1 79 1.0
## 2 70 1.0
## 3 NA 0.9
## 4 78 1.0
```